# ImageButton doesn't highlight on click with Transparent background

Tags: android, button, transparency

I've set up an ImageButton to be transparent, so the icon matches the backgrond panel like the Android ActionBar. This looks fine as I want it to.

However, when the background is transparent, there isn't the blueish highlight you see as when you press a transparent button in the action bar.

Can I have an ImageButton that is transparent and also has the highlight flash when clicked?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/nextItemButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_media_ff" />
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

All you need to do is to set the proper background. If you want it to be transparent in normal state and blueish in pressed stated.

Create a [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) like this one in `res/drawable` directory.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_bluish_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

This way the default background is transparent. When pressed the background has the color you specified (instead of color you can use any drawable here).

Comment: Unfortunately, the button highlight in the built in android styles isn't public. This is the custom color I ended up going with. Was as close as i could get to the Jelly Bean color, which I think is the same color in ICS: #057891

Using the StateListDrawable worked great.

Comment: The default pressed color depends on the device and the version of Android it is running. The Holo theme uses semitransparent bluish 9-patch drawable in the pressed state.

Answer (score 143):

I came across this same problem.  Finally, I got a sample of a code with that attribute:

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

This attibute will give a transparent background with selectable highlight to any View (Button, ImageButton, TextView...) **WITHOUT MORE CODING!!!**

Comment: If you're using ActionBarSherlock, use android:background="?selectableItemBackground" instead.

Comment: Can this be set to a view programmatically?

Comment: Good solution, but requires Api level 11 :/

Comment: For those who were wondering, this lives in attrs... Personally I'd use it in its fully qualified state "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" to keep it readable

Comment: This should be selected as the best answer.

Comment: Totally agree, this should be the selected answer

Comment: Definetely the best answer, I've been searching for this specifically, thanks!!

Comment: this should be the best answer

Answer (score 10):

Just to add on Fernandez good answer:

If you want the effect to be Round and not rectangle use:

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

(*for V21 and up).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it programmatically, here is one solution:

Create a custom `ImageButton` class and Override `drawableStateChange()`:

```
public class CustomImageButton extends ImageButton {

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        Log.d("Button", "isPressed: " + isPressed() );
        if( isPressed() ){
            setBackgroundResource( android.R.color.holo_blue_dark );
        }  else {
            setBackgroundResource( android.R.color.transparent );
        }
        super.drawableStateChanged();

    }

    public CustomImageButton( Context context ) {
        super( context );
    }

    public CustomImageButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    public CustomImageButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle ) {
        super( context, attrs, defStyle );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



}
```