# Make borderless image button small on Android

Tags: android, button, borderless

There is some closeable view in my app and it has a close button in header. I want make this button borderless and small.
The code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"/>
```

In result the button is borderless but has much empty place around cross image (button is hitted on screenshot to make empty space visible)
[image]

 How could I fix it?

Comment: will you share image of your output ......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use:

```
  android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: Couldn't check your solution, but I believe it workable and it looks pretty. Accepted!

Answer (score 3):

Added

```
 android:minHeight="0dp"
 android:minWidth="0dp"
 android:padding="2dp"
```

The result 
[image]


Also I'll use negative margins to place the button closer to corner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following on your ImageButton to remove the 'border':

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or

```
android:background="@null"
```

If you would like change the background when the user clicks the button you can create a selector. Example [ImageButton doesn't highlight on click with Transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825613/imagebutton-doesnt-highlight-on-click-with-transparent-background).

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/), you can use constraints to reduce the width of the borderless `ImageButton`, that's way too wide by default, by constraining it to be as wide as the height:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_closeable_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_close"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't recommend you to make it any smaller than this because the touch target needs to be at least 48dp x 48dp, as for [Google's Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/design/usability/accessibility.html#layout-typography), otherwise a user would have a hard time trying to touch it.

If you really need it to look like it's closer to the edges of the view, you can always use an image that's not centered (has transparent padding on one or two sides), but I'd try my best to avoid doing this workaround and try rethinking my app's design in order to accommodate the button as it is.

Answer (score -1):

use textView for that..
 and use textview.OnTouchListener
 finally onTouch change the color of text.. thats it

or else in your code just use

```
     android:background="@null"
```

Comment: I believe there is more admissible solution

Comment: <ImageButton>android:background="@null"</ImageButton> use this..this is the only one solution

Comment: @snehasish but then it prevents the button from being highlighted when pressed.